# C# Binding images from XML to LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xml, image, windows-phone-8, binding

I have a problem where I'm trying to show some images from my List inside my **LongListSelector**, but when I'm trying to bind my **LongListSelector** to my `List` which contains my images, it wont show any images.

My **LongListSelector** in `XAML`:

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Images">
    <Grid>
        <phone:LongListSelector LayoutMode="Grid" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GridCellSize="180,180" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="5">
                    <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Images}"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

and my DataContext:

```
this.DataContext = gd.GetGameItems;
```

The ObservableCollection im binding to my LongListSelector which contains my List Images:

```
 private ObservableCollection<GetGame> _GetGameItems = new ObservableCollection<GetGame>();
    public ObservableCollection<GetGame> GetGameItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this._GetGameItems;
        }
    }
```

The code to read the XML and to store data. The method GetImages is where im getting the images and putting them into my List(Images) from the XML which i would like to show in my LongListSelector. The class GetGame is where i store my data:

```
var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var gameData = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Game").Select(x => new GetGame
            {
                ID = (int)x.Element("id"),
                GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
                Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform"),
                ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
                Images = GetImages(x).ToList(),

            })
              .ToList();
            foreach (var item in gameData)
            {
                GetGameItems.Add(item);
            }         

private static IEnumerable<Uri> GetImages(XElement gameNode)
    {
        return gameNode
                  .Descendants("boxart")
                  .Select(t => new Uri("http://thegamesdb.net/banners/" + (string)t.Attribute("thumb")));
    }

public class GetGame
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public List<Uri> Images { get; set; }
}
```

This is my XML:

```
    <Data>
  <baseImgUrl>http://thegamesdb.net/banners/</baseImgUrl>
  <Game>
    <id>2</id>
    <GameTitle>Crysis</GameTitle>
     <PlatformId>1</PlatformId>
     <Platform>PC</Platform>
     <ReleaseDate>11/13/2007</ReleaseDate>
     <Overview>
     From the makers of Far Cry, Crysis offers FPS fans the best-looking, most highly-        evolving gameplay, requiring the player to use adaptive tactics and total customization of    weapons and armor to survive in dynamic, hostile environments including Zero-G. Earth, 2019. A team of US scientists makes a frightening discovery on an island in the South China Sea. All contact with the team is lost when the North Korean Government quickly seals off the area. The United States responds by dispatching an elite team of Delta Force Operators to recon the situation. As tension rises between the two nations, a massive alien ship reveals itself in the middle of the island. The ship generates an immense force sphere that freezes a vast portion of the island and drastically alters the global weather system. Now the US and North Korea must join forces to battle the alien menace. With hope rapidly fading, you must fight epic battles through tropical jungle, frozen landscapes, and finally into the heart of the alien ship itself for the ultimate Zero G showdown.
    </Overview>
    <ESRB>M - Mature</ESRB>
    <Genres>
    <genre>Shooter</genre>
    </Genres>
    <Players>4+</Players>
    <Co-op>No</Co-op>
    <Youtube>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3vO01xQ-DM</Youtube>
    <Publisher>Electronic Arts</Publisher>
    <Developer>Crytek</Developer>
    <Rating>8.1111</Rating>
    <Images>
      <fanart>
        <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-1.jpg</original>
        <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-1.jpg</thumb>
      </fanart>
      <fanart>
        <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-2.jpg</original>
        <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-2.jpg</thumb>
      </fanart>
      <fanart>
        <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-3.jpg</original>
        <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-3.jpg</thumb>
      </fanart>
      <fanart>
        <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-4.jpg</original>
        <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-4.jpg</thumb>
      </fanart>
      <fanart>
        <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-5.jpg</original>
        <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-5.jpg</thumb>
      </fanart>
      <fanart>
        <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-6.jpg</original>
        <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-6.jpg</thumb>
      </fanart>
    <boxart side="back" width="1525" height="2162" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/back/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/back/2-1.jpg</boxart>
    <boxart side="front" width="1525" height="2160" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/front/2-1.jpg</boxart>
    <banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g2.jpg</banner>
    <banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g3.jpg</banner>
      <screenshot>
        <original width="1920" height="1080">screenshots/2-1.jpg</original>
        <thumb>screenshots/thumb/2-1.jpg</thumb>
      </screenshot>
    <clearlogo width="400" height="95">clearlogo/2.png</clearlogo>
    </Images>
  </Game>
</Data>
```

So, the problem is getting this List with images to show up in my LongListSelector. I don't know if it has something to do with that my List Images is inside my ObservableCollection GetGameItems:

```
public List<Uri> Images { get; set; }
```

I hope there is someone that can help me, Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# binding images from a List inside a ObservableCollection to show in LongListSelector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061203/c-sharp-binding-images-from-a-list-inside-a-observablecollection-to-show-in-long)

Comment: you can't bind images with a URl, create  a new bitmap from url and bind.

Comment: @Jaihind Okay, can you give me a example maybe?, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be because you are trying to bind a List as image source, trying binding to another longlist selector, this worked for me

```
<phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyList" LayoutMode="List" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameTitle}" />
                                <phone:LongListSelector LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="180,180" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                                </phone:LongListSelector>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Yes it works!, i dont understand why this works, but it does!. Thanks! :).

Comment: Can you tell me why this works? and does it have any negative effect that there is a LongListSelector inside another LongListSelector?.

Comment: To put in simple terms you were trying to bind a list of items to a control(image) that could handle only one item (item being the image uri), so you need to specify a control that could handle a variable list of those items. for the second question depending on your data you may face performance issues because of using nested LongListSelector and it is not a recommended UI scenario, i dont have the optimal solution on top of my mind now but i would advise you to split the page into two meaning one page showing game title and another page showing the screenshots on selection.

Comment: Damn i found out that this doesn't work. With some images my app crashes and i get this error message:  Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete. :/

Comment: Strange, if i set the image control height and width manually it works fine ? for example: Height="100" Width="100"

Answer (score 0):

```
<phone:LongListSelector LayoutMode="Grid" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GridCellSize="180,180" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="5">
                <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. It still wont show the images :(.

Comment: Does you parsing provide valid images url?

Comment: Yes, i just checked it. The LongListSelector wont show any images.

Comment: Is it because the images must be Bitmap images?

Comment: jpeg, png are supported. check for bmp on msdn if you need bmp